# Typescript extra return properties when defining return type in function type

Tags: typescript

The following example illustrates my issue pretty well:

```
type Position = {
  x: number
  y: number
}

const update = (): Position => ({ x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }) // 'z' does not exist in type 'Position', as it should.

type Update = () => Position

const update: Update = () => ({ x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }) // that's fine?

const position: Position = update() // so is this, even though it is clearly wrong.
```

What if I want to type this functions in a separate file? Other than adding the return type to the actual function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare that an object must be of an interface, you are saying that it must have *at least* those properties, not *only* those properties.

Typescript will complain when you are creating an object from scratch (aka an object literal) with properties that are not known to the interface, but if the object is a variable then you won't get any error when using it to fulfill an interface.

This is ok:

```
const xyz = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };

const position1: Position = xyz;
```

But this gives error "Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'z' does not exist in type 'Position'"

```
const position2: Position = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };
```

Your final example `const position: Position = update()` is actually fine because `update()` returns something that extends `Position`.  You could be even more restrictive and say `const position: {x: number} = update()` and that's fine too, as long at the value has *at least* `{x: number}`.  The object in your variable `position` will still have `y` and `z` properties, but you'll get an error when trying to access them because typescript doesn't know about them.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to link to the handbook documentation about [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)